# grouping matching error, django url dispatcher

Tags: python, regex, django, url-routing, django-urls

I just wondering if is it possible to create a big url pattern in django like this:

```
url(r'^/foo('/limit/(?P<limit>\d+)/|/offset/(?P<offset>\d+)/|/limit/(?P<limit>\d+)/offset/(?P<offset>\d+)/|/offset/(?P<offset>\d+)/limit/(?P<limit>\d+)/?$', 'foo', name='foo'),
```

to avoid write:

```
url(r'^/foo/limit/(?P<limit>\d+)/?$', 'foo', name='foo'),
url(r'^/foo/offset/(?P<offset>\d+)/?$', 'foo', name='foo'),
url(r'^/foo/limit/(?P<limit>\d+)/offset/(?P<offset>\d+)/?$', 'foo', name='foo'),
url(r'^/foo//offset/(?P<offset>\d+)/limit/(?P<limit>\d+)/?$', 'foo', name='foo'),
```

I'm getting a grouping error with the first one.

my goal is to write just one url per endpoint in order to speed up django search url regex pattern due to if I write tons of url patterns takes a lot, although will be easier to just write one url per endpoint and make `limit`, `offset` optional, but that is not working when I want to write `/foo/offset/1/limit/1` I want to be able to make the request in any order for the params (imagine I have 7 params for an endpoint... see where this is going?)

Any ideas or suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: If they're all calling the same view function, maybe it would be easier to use query string arguments? From the regexp docs: "each group name must be defined only once within a regular expression".

Comment: yeah that is current solution, I would like to do it like this. Do yo think I'm trying to complicate the things?

Comment: I think if I needed to support order-independent parameters and didn't want to just use the querystring (which remains my first choice) I'd capture multiple name/value pairs and parse them in my views. But even that is painful, since you can't just repeat the group - you'd need something like `(?(\w+)/(\d+)/)?` seven times in the URL. Ugh.

Comment: mmm I see your point, it would be really ugly to implement a solution like the name/value pairs... I guess is not possible to do it the way I wanted to do it. thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In most of the REST APIs I saw "limit" and "offset" (or "start" and "count") are query parameters:

https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_can_your_api_give_developers_just_the_information